ValueError in Tensorflow that cannot convert to a shape
Trying to fix a tensorflow model from an older version of tensorflow than what I have. I'm getting a ValueError that seems to be from a library version issue, but I'm really not sure how to fix that.
Please help me.
Here is the error message from the terminal:
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/TUMprep/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/common/variables.py", line 550, in standardize_shape
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot convert '(128, 16.0)' to a shape. Found invalid entry '16.0' of type '<class 'float'>'. 
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/TUMprep/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/oracle.py", line 545, in _check_consecutive_failures
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Number of consecutive failures exceeded the limit of 3.

I've been fixing the program and updating some of the formatting to fit the current version of tensorflow, but I don't know how to fix the library version issue. Some suggestions to fix it would be amazing!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Hi @falllll , The error message you're seeing indicates that there's a compatibility problem between the code you're executing and the version of TensorFlow/Keras installed on your system.Make sure your code is compatible with the version of TensorFlow and Keras you have installed. TensorFlow 2.x introduces several changes from TensorFlow 1.x, including how shapes and tensors are managed. Check the sections of your code where shapes are defined or modified, and ensure that all dimensions are specified as integers.

If you are using Keras Tuner for hyperparameter tuning, ensure that your tuning configurations are compatible with your TensorFlow/Keras version. Review the Keras Tuner documentation for any changes in how parameters should be defined.
